# Sharepoint Designer 2013 - overlapping requests

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

I´ve created a SharePoint list for asset management.

Asset requests can be started by creating a new item

- a request mail including the pick-up & planned return date is sent to the asset owner automatically.

I would like to add a function that checks if there is already a request for the inserted time frame or not. Like the "`avoid overlapping meetings`" function in outlook.

Thank you for your thoughts!